# Symfony dynamic form issue

Tags: symfony-forms

I try to implement dynamic form on Symfony but I get an 500 error. I follow this tutorial https://grafikart.fr/tutoriels/champs-imbriques-888 and this page https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html. But I can't find the way to resolve my issue. Here is my Code :

ProductEntity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"product"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Groups({"product"})
     */
    private $description;



    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"product"})
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable")
     */
    private $updatedAt;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Picture::class, mappedBy="product",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Groups({"product"})
     */
    private $pictures;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Color::class, mappedBy="product")
     * @Groups({"product"})
     */
    private $colors;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=SubCategory::class, inversedBy="products")
     */
    private $subCategory;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="products")
     * @Groups({"product"})
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Size::class, inversedBy="products")
     * @Groups({"product"})
     */
    private $size;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pictures = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->colors = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }



    public function getPrice(): ?int
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(int $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return Collection|Picture[]
     */
    public function getPictures(): Collection
    {
        return $this->pictures;
    }

    public function addPicture(Picture $picture): self
    {
        if (!$this->pictures->contains($picture)) {
            $this->pictures[] = $picture;
            $picture->setProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePicture(Picture $picture): self
    {
        if ($this->pictures->removeElement($picture)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($picture->getProduct() === $this) {
                $picture->setProduct(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return Collection|Color[]
     */
    public function getColors(): Collection
    {
        return $this->colors;
    }

    public function addColor(Color $color): self
    {
        if (!$this->colors->contains($color)) {
            $this->colors[] = $color;
            $color->setProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeColor(Color $color): self
    {
        if ($this->colors->removeElement($color)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($color->getProduct() === $this) {
                $color->setProduct(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSubCategory(): ?SubCategory
    {
        return $this->subCategory;
    }

    public function setSubCategory(?SubCategory $subCategory): self
    {
        $this->subCategory = $subCategory;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }


    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getSize(): ?Size
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    public function setSize(?Size $size): self
    {
        $this->size = $size;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

CategoryEntity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *  @Groups({"product", "category"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"product", "category"})
     */
    private $name;




    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @var string
     */
    private $logo;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="categories", fileNameProperty="logo")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=SubCategory::class, mappedBy="categories")
     *  @Groups({"product", "category"})
     */
    private $subCategories;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;


    // ...

    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setLogo($logo)
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getLogo()
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sizes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->subCategories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }





    /**
     * @return Collection|Size[]
     */
    public function getSizes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->sizes;
    }



    /**
     * @return Collection|SubCategory[]
     */
    public function getSubCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->subCategories;
    }

    public function addSubCategory(SubCategory $subCategory): self
    {
        if (!$this->subCategories->contains($subCategory)) {
            $this->subCategories[] = $subCategory;
            $subCategory->addCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSubCategory(SubCategory $subCategory): self
    {
        if ($this->subCategories->removeElement($subCategory)) {
            $subCategory->removeCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[] = $product;
            $product->setCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if ($this->products->removeElement($product)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getCategory() === $this) {
                $product->setCategory(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

SubCategoryEntity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\SubCategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SubCategoryRepository::class)
 */
class SubCategory
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *  @Groups({"product", "category"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *  @Groups({"product", "category"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="subCategories")
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="subCategory")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Category[]
     */
    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function addCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $this->categories[] = $category;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($category);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[] = $product;
            $product->setSubCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if ($this->products->removeElement($product)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getSubCategory() === $this) {
                $product->setSubCategory(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Most important ProductForm

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\Size;
use App\Entity\SubCategory;
use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use App\Repository\SizeRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;
use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {


        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => false, 'attr' => ['placeholder' => "Titre de l'article", 'class' => 'form-control m-2']])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class,  ['label' => false, 'attr' => ['placeholder' => "Description", 'class' => 'form-control m-2']])
            ->add(
                'size',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => Size::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control m-2'],
                    'placeholder' => "Selectionnez une taille",
                    'required' => false

                ],
            )
            ->add('price', MoneyType::class,  [

                'currency' => '',
                'label' => false,
                'scale' => 2,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Prix",
                    'type' => 'number',
                    'class' => 'form-control m-2'
                ]
            ])
            ->add(
                'category',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => Category::class,
                    'label' => "Catégories de l'article",
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control m-2'],
                    'placeholder' => "Selectionnez une catégorie",
                ],

            )->add('pictures', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ProductImageType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true
            ]);



        $builder->get('category')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                /**
                 * @var Category $category
                 */
                $category = $form->getData();


                $this->addSubCategoryField($form->getParent(), $form->getData());
            }
        );

        // $builder->addEventListener(
        //     FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
        //     function (FormEvent $event) {
        //         $form = $event->getForm();
        //         $data = $event->getData();

        //         $subCategory = $data->getSubCategory();
        //         $category = $data->getCategory();
        //         $this->addSubCategoryField($form, $category);
        //         if ($subCategory) {


        //             $form->get('subCategory')->setData($subCategory);
        //         } else {
        //         }
        //     }
        // );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ]);
    }

    function addSubCategoryField($form, ?Category $category)
    {
        // dd($category->getSubCategories());

        $form->add(
            'subCategory',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => SubCategory::class,
                'label' => "Sous catégories de l'article",
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control m-2'],
                'placeholder' =>  $category ? "Selectionnez une sous-catégorie" : "Selectionner une catégorie",
                'choices' => $category ? $category->getSubCategories() : []
            ],
        );
    }
}
```

ProductController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Picture;
use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\Size;
use App\Form\ProductType;
use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;


/**
 * @Route("/admin/product")
 */
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("", name="admin_product_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(ProductRepository $productRepository, CategoryRepository $categoryRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('admin/product/index.html.twig', [
            'products' => $productRepository->findBy([], ['updatedAt' => "DESC"])
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="admin_product_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request, CategoryRepository $categoryRepository): Response
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];

        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $productImages = $product->getPictures();
            foreach ($productImages as $key => $productImage) {
                if ($productImage->getImageFile()) {

                    $productImage->setProduct($product);
                    $productImages->set($key, $productImage);
                }
            }


            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($product);
            $entityManager->flush();

            // return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_product_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('admin/product/new.html.twig', [
            'product' => $product,
            'form' => $form,
            // 'categories' => $serializer($categoryRepository->findAll(), 'json')
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id<\d+>}", name="admin_product_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(Product $product): Response
    {
        return $this->render('admin/product/show.html.twig', [
            'product' => $product,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id<\d+>}/edit", name="admin_product_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Product $product): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $productImages = $product->getPictures();
            foreach ($productImages as $key => $productImage) {
                if ($productImage->getImageFile()) {

                    $productImage->setProduct($product);
                    $productImages->set($key, $productImage);
                }
            }
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_product_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('admin/product/edit.html.twig', [
            'product' => $product,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id<\d+>}", name="admin_product_delete", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, Product $product): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete' . $product->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($product);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_product_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }
}
```

and my template

```
{% form_theme form 'admin/product/_form_theme.html.twig' %}

{{ form_start(form, {'attr':{'class':'form-group'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.description) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.price) }}
    <div class='border rounded p-3 m-2 w-100'>
    Taille
        {{ form_widget(form.size) }}

    <a href="#">Ajouter un taille</a>
    </div>
      <div class='border rounded p-3 m-2 w-100'>
    Catégorie
    {{ form_widget(form.category) }}
    <a href="#">Ajouter un catégorie</a>
</div>
{% if form.subCategory  is defined %}
        <div class='border rounded p-3 m-2 w-100'>
    Sous catégorie
    {{ form_widget(form.subCategory) }}
    <a href="#">Ajouter une sous catégorie</a>
</div> 
{% endif %}
    {{ form_widget(form.pictures) }}
    <div>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Enregistrer</button>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}

<script>

$(document).on('change', '#product_category', function () {
  let $field = $(this)
  let target = 'product_subCategory'
  let $form = $field.closest('form')
  let data = {}
  $token = $('#product__token')

 data[$token.attr('name')] = $token.val()
 data[$field.attr('name')] = $field.val()
  $.post($form.attr('action'), data )
  .then(function (data) {

    let $input = $(data).find(target) 
    // On remplace notre <select> actuel
  })
}) 

$('.add-another-collection-widget').click(function (e) {
        var list = $($(this).attr('data-list-selector'));
        // Try to find the counter of the list or use the length of the list
        var counter = list.data('widget-counter') | list.children().length;

        // grab the prototype template
        var newWidget = list.attr('data-prototype');
        // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
        // with a number that's unique to your emails
        // end name attribute looks like name="contact[emails][2]"
        newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter);
        // Increase the counter
        counter++;
        // And store it, the length cannot be used if deleting widgets is allowed
        list.data('widget-counter', counter);
        // create a new list element and add it to the list
        var newElem = $(list.attr('data-widget-tags')).html(newWidget);
        newElem.appendTo(list);
    });

</script>
```

I can't understand why I submit form with the button I get the subCategory field but if I post by ajax way I got an 500 error (An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null)

May someone helps me pliiiiiiz :)

Comment: And of course I don't want to persist until all required fields are fill

Answer (score 0):

'done

```
{% form_theme form 'admin/product/_form_theme.html.twig' %}
{% set subCategory = false%}
{{ form_start(form, {'attr':{'class':'form-group'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.description) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.price, {attr:{type:"number"}}) }}
    <div class='border rounded p-3 m-2 w-100'>
    Taille
        {{ form_widget(form.size) }}

    <a href="#">Ajouter un taille</a>
    </div>
      <div class='border rounded p-3 m-2 w-100'>
    Catégorie
    {{ form_widget(form.category) }}
    <a href="#">Ajouter un catégorie</a>
  </div>
  <div class="subCategory">
{% if subCategory %}

{% endif %}
</div> 

    {{ form_widget(form.pictures) }}
    <div>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Enregistrer</button>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}

<script>
let test = ""
$(document).on('change', '#product_category', function () {
  let $field = $(this)
  let target = '#product_subCategory'

  let $form = $field.closest('form')

  let data = {}
  data["product[name]"] = $('input[name="product[name]"]').val()
  data["product[description]"] = $('textarea[name="product[description]"]').val()
  data["product[price]"] = $('input[name="product[price]"]').val()
  data["product[size]"] =  $('select[name="product[size]"]').val()

  $token = $('#product__token')
  data[$token.attr('name')] = $token.val()
 data[$field.attr('name')] = $field.val()

 if(  data["product[name]"] !="" &&   data["product[desc]"] !="" &&   data["product[price]"] !=""){
  $.post($form.attr('action'), data )
  .then(function (data) {
    let $input = $(data).find(target) 
test = $input
    const subCategoryField = `<div class='border rounded p-3 m-2 w-100'>
      Sous catégorie
      <select id="product_subCategory" name="product[subCategory]" required="required" class="form-control m-2">
      ${$input.html()}
      </select>
      <a href="#">Ajouter une sous catégorie</a>
      </div>`
  $(".subCategory").replaceWith(subCategoryField)

  {% set subCategory = true %}
    })
  }
}) 

$('.add-another-collection-widget').click(function (e) {
        var list = $($(this).attr('data-list-selector'));
        // Try to find the counter of the list or use the length of the list
        var counter = list.data('widget-counter') | list.children().length;

        // grab the prototype template
        var newWidget = list.attr('data-prototype');
        // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
        // with a number that's unique to your emails
        // end name attribute looks like name="contact[emails][2]"
        newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter);
        // Increase the counter
        counter++;
        // And store it, the length cannot be used if deleting widgets is allowed
        list.data('widget-counter', counter);
        // create a new list element and add it to the list
        var newElem = $(list.attr('data-widget-tags')).html(newWidget);
        newElem.appendTo(list);
    });

</script>
```

hope help someone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).